# Is it possible for extremely ingenious but elementary proofs for famous problems to exist?

Tags: number-theory, education, problem-solving, open-problem, big-picture

As Erdős put it, "Mathematics is not ready for such problems." when faced with the great conjecture of Collatz.

So is it impossible altogether for simple but ***ingenious*** proofs for famous problems like Fermat's Last Theorem, Goldbach's conjecture...etc to exist?

In other words, is it possible to solve such problems without consulting the "higher" domains of mathematics or seeking new domains to reach a solution?

E.g; Fermat claimed a proof for his Last Theorem, and it is quite probable that it was within elementary bounds (if it even existed), atleast by our standard today.

Comment: Didn't he say that when faced with the Collatz Conjecture?, Also interesting read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function_arithmetic#Friedman.27s_grand_conjecture

Comment: It is I think unreasonable to believe Fermat had a proof. As to the claim, as Descartes observed, Fermat was a Gascon.

Comment: Possible, yes, very likely, no.

Comment: One usually thinks made an error in his proof (worthy of him)  : he supposed that what we call nowadays rings of algebraic integers are principal, whereas they're only Dedekind, in general.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, K. Ribet has pointed out a very specific error that Fermat might have been assuming in his mind when he wrote the famous margin comment, where this error would lead to a fallacious proof of FLT; in modern terms, that certain rings had unique factorization, when they really don't. This was said out loud, I'm not sure Ribet ever published this comment.

Answer (score 5):

In 2013, Yitang Zhang made major inroads on [prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap).

Quite likely, there will eventually be very short proofs on the [Sierpinski number conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number) and the [Riesel number conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesel_number).

[Pentagon tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling) just got a fifteenth solution.

A [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of order 428 was found in 2005, and eventually the order 668 will be found.

Some perfect solutions in the [Kobon Triangle Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobon_triangle_problem) were found recently.

The optimal way to [cover a triangle with 2 squares](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squcotri/) wasn't found until 2009.

For the [Euler sum of powers conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture), the proof it was *wrong* was simple.

$27^5 + 84^5 + 110^5 + 133^5 = 144^5$ (Lander & Parkin, 1966)

Euler also conjectured there was no [Graeco-Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square) of order 10, which was proven wrong in 1959 by a counterexample.

It's inevitable that a highly elegant proof or new wonderful example will come out for some currently unsolved problem. For some of these, there might be thousands of computer-years involved in the attack, but that will boil down to a short list of facts that fit on a single page and are easily checked.

There likely won't be a simple proof for *those* problems, though. But other, less studied problems, particularly those vulnerable to computerized insight -- yes, some of them will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The example which immediately comes to mind is the elementary proof of the prime number theorem by Erdős and Selberg.

Comment: But this wasn't the original proof of the theorem! It seems possible that elementary proofs "out of the blue" for famous open problems are extremely unlikely (to the point of being unheard of), but that once the problem has been settled and is extremely well-understood, an elementary proof may become possible.

Comment: You make a good point. I was showing, by example that such a proof can exist. It may have been possible for someone to come up with an elementary proof of the prime number number theorem before the original proof since such a proof exists. The OP asks if such a proof is possible, not how likely it is.

Comment: One famous example is Apery's proof that $\zeta(3)=1+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{4^3}+\cdots$ is irrational.